# Why does Array.prototype.includes.bind behave unexpectedly?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Given existing googleable knowledge of `function.bind` and such, and the following control code:

```js
console.log( [1, 2, 3].includes(2) ) // --> `true` 
console.log( [null].map(String.prototype.toUpperCase, "abc") ) // --> `["ABC"]`  
console.log( Array.prototype.includes.bind([3, 4, 5])(1) ) //--> `false`  
console.log( Array.prototype.includes.bind([3, 4, 5])(4) ) // -- > `true`
```

`_` is underscorejs, a generic utility wrapper/polyfill thing

```
[1, 2, 3].some(_.prototype.includes.bind(_([3, 4, 5]))) // --> `true`
```

But, why does this code yield this unexpected result?

```js
console.log(
  [1,2,3].some(Array.prototype.includes.bind([3,4,5])) // --> `false`
)
```

Edit: I know this code is bad form in its literal form, but this is a POC, the real implementation will differ (and cannot use arrow functions, thanks IE)

Comment: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the syntax for [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```
arr.includes(valueToFind, [fromIndex])
```

There is an optional second parameter `fromIndex`.

> `fromIndex`: The position in this array at which to begin searching for valueToFind

So, your code becomes something like this:

```
[1,2,3].some((a,index) => Array.prototype.includes.bind([3,4,5])(a, index))
// OR
[1,2,3].some((a, index) => [3,4,5].includes(a, index))
```

It is looking for `3` starting from the `index = 2`.

So, if you were to change it like this, it will return `true`

```js
console.log(
  // looks for from index=0
  [3,2,1].some(Array.prototype.includes.bind([5,4,3]))
)
```

Comment: ah dangit, you and @Grillparzer are right, the `some` index variable is passed into the `includes` fromIndex, breaking the concept. It works with underscore because it doesn't use a second variable. Thanks for pointing it out, I was overlooking this

Answer (score 2):

What you may not be expecting is that .some() invokes the bound function with three parameters, and not just the one that contains the value.

You can check this with `[1,2,3].some(console.log)`

Array.includes accepts two parameters, one for the value and an optional one that offsets the start location.

A solution would be:

`[3,2,1].some(n => Array.prototype.includes.bind([5,4,3])(n))`